# Adding name and id properties to textarea (struts)

Tags: java, struts, struts-html

i mostly do CSS and php so i'm kind'a lost here, so no idea if this is possible the way i want it anyway, this is it:

I have this code

```
<html:textarea rows="10" cols="70" property="thankYouMessage" />
```

And i want this textarea to render an id of "textareaID" and a name like "textareaname"

how can i go about this?... if i use styleID, the page just won't load anymore... i need to apply some css to that markup so that's the thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`styleId` attribute should work (perhaps you mispelled it ? case is sensitive)

```
<html:textarea styleId="textareaID" property="thankYouMessage" ... />
```

IIRC (long time since Struts 1...) the generated `name` atribute in the HTML tag will coincide with the `property` attribute ([ref](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/textarea.html)). So in your example the generated HTML (you should check this, looking at the HTML source) should result in something like this:

```
<textarea id="textareaID" name="thankYouMessage" ...>
```

Normally you should'nt rely on `name` for accessing the element (e.g., in Javascript), prefer the `id`

Comment: you're right i mispelled that, shame on me, but what about the name atribute? thanks for your answer!